# using assertions in an unordered collection

Tags: java, unit-testing, collections

I'm inserting a `Collection<Event>` inside a table, something like this

```
Collection<Event> eventCollection = service.insert(events);
```

Now, I need to test that `Event`s in `eventCollection` has certain attributes. I'm not sure about the order, in which, `Event`s are stored in `eventCollection`. Currently, this is how I'm doing the assertions.

```
assertTrue(
        Iterables.get(eventCollection, 0).getPojo.getField1()
            .equals("Some Value") &&
            Iterables.get(eventCollection, 0).getPojo.getField2()
            .equals("Some Value") &&
            Iterables.get(eventCollection, 0).getPojo.getField3()
            .equals("Some Value") &&                
            Iterables.get(eventCollection, 1).getPojo.getField1()
            .equals("Some Value") &&
            eventCollection, 1).getPojo.getField2()
            .equals("Some Value") &&
            Iterables.get(eventCollection, 1).getPojo.getField3()
            .equals("Some Value"))
    );
```

I know that there are two elements in `eventCollection`, but I'm not sure what order they're in. `Iterables.get` seem to work fine, but I'm wondering if there's any easier/shorter way to do this using stream api?

Edit: `"Some Value"` doesn't always necessarily refer to `String`.

Comment: `Set<String> set = eventCollection.stream().map(Pojo::getField).collectors(Collectors.toSet()); set.contains(....) && set.contains(....)`

Comment: @Eugene The map needs to contain multiple fields of different type.

Comment: When you accept an answer that checks whether all events have exactly the same properties—why did you ever bother about their order in the collection?

Comment: @Holger The Collection might have the same Pojo(s), but their instantiations are mutually exclusive to each other. I accepted the answer because it's the closest to the solution I was looking for, where I don't need to use the index(es) as with `Iterables.get()` but rather make usage of stream API along with some conditions that satisfy the requirement of how the pojos are expected to be returned as! Btw, my solution contains a combination of `||` and `&&` operators. The answer just provided me with an idea of how to carry it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum clarity I would suggest encapsulating the low-level predicate into a helper method, and using [Stream.allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) to do the check.

Helper function (assumed placed in class `Context`, exact location does not matter):

```
public static boolean expectedValues(Event event) {
    return event.getPojo().getField1().equals("Some Value") &&
            event.getPojo().getField2().equals("Some Value") &&
            event.getPojo().getField3().equals("Some Value");
}
```

The actual check, which is indeed much more self-explanatory:

```
assertTrue(eventCollection.stream().allMatch(Context::expectedValues));
```